# Wordpress replace plugin function with own one

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I use woocommerce plugin in my WordPress site. In the plugin there is function  widget(), I want to call  my own function, so when site loads, instead of plugin function

```
public function widget($args, $instance)
```

my function will be called.

I think it should be done with add_filter, by I can't find out how.

Plugin file directory is:

```
woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php
```

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: What's your end goal? *Why* do you need to fully replace this function?

Comment: Also, which function are you trying to replace?

Comment: @Dre, from the question: [function widget()](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-layered-nav.php#L121).

Comment: That's part of a class definition, making it a method, not a function. This means it's not so straightforward to replace. @rnevius asked, what's your end goal? Rather than trying to replace the method, you might need to create your own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try below code (place it in your WordPress theme functions.php)

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_widget_replacement', 11 );

function my_widget_replacement() {
    unregister_widget( 'WC_Widget_Layered_Nav' );
    register_widget( 'My_WC_Widget_Layered_Nav' );
}


class My_WC_Widget_Layered_Nav extends WC_Widget_Layered_Nav {
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

This code may not work - it's just an idea.